# How do I sketch a vector function such as $ \mathbf{v} = \frac{\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{r^2} $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I am studying Griffiths Introduction to electrodynamics and stumbled upon problem 1.16, it says,

Sketch the vector function
$ \mathbf{v} = \frac{\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{r^2} $
and compute its divergence. The answer may surprise you. . . can you explain it?

I have calculated its divergence and it is $0$, however, I can't imagine how the vector field looks like. Can someone tell me how to?

Comment: Note that the divergence is $0$ at all points except for the origin. At the origin it's infinity, but a very specific kind of infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to remember that $$\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
           z
\end{bmatrix}$$
So that the vector field $\mathbf{v}$ has radial direction $($because it has the same direction as $\hat{\mathbf{r}})$ but it's multiplied by a factor $r^{-2}$ which goes to zero as $r$ approaches infinity. In the end, it's quiver plot looks something like this

[image]